# Bitcoin core wallet

Tags: wallet

Can anyone point me in the right direction I downloaded the bitcoin core qt wallet wee while back all the files that come with it are everywhere not in the right path I don’t know much about this there’s a lot of files just don’t know what to do with them would anyone have a idea for someone who knows where little about it which would be the easiest way to generate a new wallet to something that would be simple for me to use and what files to look out for some of the ones I’ve seen is a about rsa key,files about generating keys,wallet hash tree I think it was pools and stuff I’ve just no idea thanks

Answer (score 0):

> all the files that come with it are everywhere not in the right path [...] there’s a lot of files just don’t know what to do with them

What you wrote suggests you downloaded the source files. If I wanted to do this I'd follow guidance at https://www.google.com/search?q=build+bitcoin+core+from+source but I suspect you are not comfortable with this, so instead ...

I suggest you download the single-file precompiled-installer for your operating system from https://bitcoincore.org/en/download/ and run that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply I went onto it thats where I got my new wallet I downloaded that to see what to look for, for my old wallet to remember I thought I could transfer it over or generate that into my old wallet